# Unresolved Reference "placeresponse"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am new to coding, so was using the google developer tutorial to create an app. I was doing this letter by letter so I am not sure why I have an unresolved reference for PlaceResponse. I have created a data class, which I have changed from var and val but unfortunately I must have missed something because the code below is still having issues placeresponse is being labelled as an unresolved reference

```
    fun read(): List<Place> {
        var itemType = object : TypeToken<List<PlacesResponse>>() {}.type
        var reader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        return gson.fromJson<List<PlaceResponse>>(reader, itemType).map {
            it.toPlace()
        }
    }
}

private val places: List<Place> by lazy{
    PlacesReader(this).read()
}
data class Place(
    val name:String,
    val LatLng:LatLng,
    val address: String,
    val rating: Float
```

Comment: If is unresolved is because PlaceResponse is not declared anywhere. Are you sure that you are not able to create a List<Place> directly?

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding, what do you mean by creating a List<place> directly @appersiano?

Comment: I mean that if your json is simply a list con place you can map it directly. Anyway check the official doc with examples https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: Thanks @appersiano I will give it a read